# Notation for infinite product in reverse order

Tags: notation

This question is related to notation of infinite product.

We know that,
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}=x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}\cdots
$$

How do I denote
$$
    \cdots x_{3}x_{2}x_{1}  ?   
$$

One approach could be 
$$
\prod_{i=\infty}^{1}x_{i}=\cdots x_{3}x_{2}x_{1}
$$

I need to use this expression in a bigger expression so I need a good notation for this. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What about simply $\,\,...x_3x_2x_1\,\,$?

Comment: What is the difference between the two products?

Comment: As I said there a big expression in which this sits. It is confusing and looks awkward. @ Michael Greinecker If matrices are involved you can tell the difference.

Comment: Presumably, the OP is regarding non-communicative multiplication.

Comment: I think the important question is "What do you mean by $\cdots x_3 x_2 x_1$?"

Comment: I have infinite matrices which have to be multiplied.

Comment: I would interpret the "backwards product" as the limit of $x_n x_{n-1} \cdots x_1$ as $n \to \infty$, so for commutative multiplication this is the same as the usual "forward product".

Answer (score 8):

Is there any reason to avoid the obvious $\;\; \displaystyle\prod_{i=-\infty}^{-1} x_{-i} \;\;$ ?

(as opposed to dropping the negative signs, like in the approach you suggested)

Comment: Yes, this is possible! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes in Clifford algebra when they do products backwards they talk of the "reverse" of the product. I've seen this denoted various ways with tidles: $\widetilde{abc}=cba$ or $(abc)^{\sim}=cba$. If you like them you could consider 
$$\widetilde{\Pi_{i=1}^\infty a_i}$$ or $$(\Pi_{i=1}^\infty a_i)^\sim$$

Comment: I will check if this standard notation and use this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If they’re matrices, you can of course simply use $$\left(\prod_{n\ge 0}x_n^T\right)^T\;.$$

Comment: Similar to the above, we can also define $\left(\displaystyle \prod_{n \geq 0} x_n^{-1}\right)^{-1}$ assuming it makes sense to talk of $x_n^{-1}$

Answer (score 2):

In the theory of non-autonomous abstract evolution equations, it is quite costumary to use the followiong notation:

For a family of operators
$U_0,U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1}\in\mathcal{L}(X)$, we denote the "time-ordered"
product of these operators by
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{p=0}^{n-1}U_p:=U_{n-1} U_{n-2} \cdots U_1
U_0\quad\mbox{and}\quad\prod_{p=n-1}^{0}U_p:=U_0U_1\cdots U_{n-2}
U_{n-1} .
\end{equation*}

See [Pazy](http://books.google.hu/books/about/Semigroups_of_Linear_Operators_and_Appli.html?id=sIAyOgM4R3kC&redir_esc=y), Page 130.

Answer (score 1):

(With tongue in cheek:) what about this?
$$\left(x_n\prod_{i=1}^\infty \right)\;$$